# Redirecionar página caso tenha resolução menor que 767px

Tags: javascript

**Pesquisando na internet, encontrei essa pergunta aqui no SOpt:**

[Redirecionamento para site em versão mobile](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83576/redirecionamento-para-site-em-vers%C3%A3o-mobile)

Na pergunta foi colocada um código que redireciona uma página caso seja acessada por algum dispositivo móvel (mobile).

Estou utilizando aqui e funciona normalmente. Achei que seria mais interessante redirecionar caso a página seja exibida em resolução menor que 767px.

Segue o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url_mobile = "http://SEU_SITE_MOBILE";
(function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,url_mobile);
</script>
```

> Agora vem a dúvida: Como fazer o redirecionamento caso seja exibido com resolução menor que 767px?

Comment: @media queries não é do CSS?

Comment: Seria algo do tipo. :)

Comment: Mas se @media queries for do CSS como vai fazer um script em CSS kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Confundi lendo o comentário do cara, rsrsrs #Atualizei :P

Comment: Não é duplicata!

Answer (score 3):

Sem utilizar JQuery, você pode verificar a largura da janela, por exemplo, através das propriedades:

- `document.documentElement.clientWidth` largura do documento
- `window.innerWidth` largura do browser (com barra de scroll)
- `window.outerWidth` largura total da janela do browser

[Aqui](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/), tem uma lista (dinâmica) mais completa dessas propriedades.

E redirecionar com um dos comandos:

```
window.location.href = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/';
// ou
window.location.replace('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/');
// ou
window.location = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/';
// ou
window.location.assign('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/');
```

*Edit: conforme os comentários, é necessário testar em vários navegadores (inclusive em celulares) diferentes, para confirmar quais comandos funcionam para cada plataforma.*

Código de exemplo:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    window.location.href = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com/';
};
```

Comment: Não está funcionando. Você testou esse exemplo? :3

Comment: Sim, está funcionando! :P

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Legal!! Testei o código em 4 browsers: Firefox, Opera, Chrome e Safari, e funcionou sem problemas

Comment: Vou ver agora como vai ficar na página, só um momentinho :3

Comment: Testei aqui pelo celular e não está redirecionando, só quando redimensiono pelo computador :(

Comment: Acredito que no celular, redirecionar para um domínio diferente (ex: `http://diferente/`) não irá funcionar, por motivo de segurança (testei com um Android). Provavelmente, o redirect só funcionará para o mesmo domínio (ex: `/xx/yy/zzz.html`)

Comment: Sim, eu fiz para o mesmo domínio :/ Tem horas que funciona, tem horas que não... Meio loko...

Answer (score 3):

Conheço duas maneiras bem práticas.

1: acessando o `innerWidth` do `window`

`if(window.innerWidth < 767) {...}`

2: usando media queries, veja mais no [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

`if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) {..}`

Answer (score 1):

Talvez isso funcione:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {

var height = window.screen.availHeight;
var width = window.screen.availWidth;

$("#resolution").html("Height: " + height + "," + " Width: " + width);

if (width == "767" || width < "767") {
  
  window.location.href = "http://site_mobile.com";
  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="resolution"></div>
```

Comment: Não funcionou não.

Comment: Acho que o problema é que não tem o `window.location`

Comment: Tá funcionando não, acho que nem você testou kkkkkkkkk

Comment: testei nao hihihihihhi vou ver aqui